# jQuery Serialization Ignoring Field Type of Email

Tags: jquery, serialization

I have the following (basic) form structure setup:

```
<form id="userModalForm" method="post" action="#" class="acctForm">
    <div class="container-form">
        <div class="container-form" id="emailRow">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required data-err-msg="Email is required" />
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="userId" />
        <input type="button" id="saveUser" value="Save User" /><input class="cancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
    </div>
</form>
```

When the `saveUser` button is clicked, it does a jQuery AJAX POST to a backend API in order to save the form. The strange thing I'm running into is if I do `$("#userModalForm").serialize()` in the console, it won't pick up the email input on this form. When I change the `type` from `email` to `text` though, serialization sees the field and everything works as expected.

Any guesses on why jQuery's serialization doesn't see inputs with a type of email? I've tried searching and I'm not finding anything. If the input wasn't serializing with a type of `text` it'd be one thing, but the fact that it only won't when the type is `email` is really confusing.

We're on jQuery 3.2.1 if that helps - thanks!

Comment: Do you have a click event attached to the `saveUser` button somewhere? If so could you post that code?

Comment: I do, but this issue happens when I run `$("#userModalForm")` in the console even - before any save attempts. The data wasn't coming over, so I tried running it there just to see what was happening and sure enough - it didn't serialize it. When the input's type is `text`, it does.

Comment: The reason I asked is because in this fiddle it appears to work fine - so I wanted to see how you have the click event setup. https://jsfiddle.net/w9cbm3bt/7/

Comment: That's so weird, because it's definitely not happening on my side. There must be something else happening though, so thanks!

Comment: if you're able to, show me some more of the code structure so I can try to play around with it some more.